# How do I select the first, second, or third digit from a String containing three digits?

Tags: java, string, char, int

So say the code goes like this..

```
String nbr = input.nextLine();    // For example say it's 258
int a;    // I want this to be the first digit of nbr
int b;    // This the second
int c;    // And this the third
```

I tried charAt() and I couldn't find anything else...
Thanks in advance guys! Still learning!

Comment: You tried charAt() and ... what's the problem?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Comment: Integer.parseInt(nbr.substring(0,1))...

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is... charAt() gives you the char you want. You convert it to an int. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

```
String nbr = input.nextLine();    
int a=nbr.charAt(0)-'0';    
int b=nbr.charAt(1)-'0';    
int c=nbr.charAt(2)-'0';
```

Also, you could use substring and parse the result Using `Integer.parseInt`

```
int a=Integer.parseInt(nbr.substring(0,1)); //Contains the leftmost digit
```

Comment: The first option you gave me works! Thank you very much! I'm not sure why the charAt() wasn't working beforehand... Maybe wasn't using it correctly but the issue is resolved now!

Comment: charAt() returns the character's unicode code, not the numeric representation of the character. So "258".charAt(0) has the unicode code of the char '2' which is 50, not 2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is charAt() returns a char. You just need to convert it, e.g:

`int a = Character.getNumericValue(nbr.charAt(0));`

Comment: it says : Cannot invoke charAt(int) on primitive type int... Any help?

Comment: @Austin Load `nbr` should be a String, retrieved via `String nbr = input.nextLine()`